# sticky footer throws off positioning of alert messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this demo app http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer-navbar.html to create a sticky footer for a Rails app with Twitterbootstrap.  The essential html and css is below. The tutorial basically adds a #wrap div, inside of which at the bottom there's a "#push" div, and below the #wrap div there's a #footer div which  sticks at the bottom no matter what thanks to the css.

The tutorial doesn't seem to account for Twitter bootstrap alerts. In my Rails app, after applying the code from the tutorial, the alerts were invisible because they were positioned where the nav bar is. I therefore added this

```
.alert{
  margin-top: 45px;
}
```

but it moved everything below the alerts down 45px as well.

Question: Is there a way to move the .alert down 45 px without moving the html below it down as well?

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
      <div id="flash_notice">Signed in successfully.</div>
    </div>

  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"></div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <div id="push"></div>

</div>
<div id="footer"></div>


css
 html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
      }

  /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
  #wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
  }

  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  #push,
  #footer {
    height: 60px;
  }
  #footer {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }

  /* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    #footer {
      margin-left: -20px;
      margin-right: -20px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
  }
```

The big white space in this image is a result of the html getting pushed down after I added `margin-top: 45px;` to the `.alert` class
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
.alert{
 position:absolute;
 right:20px;
 top:45px;
 }
```

If this seems to help, then you could refine the positioning.

Without having a jsFiddle or something to test this on I'm not sure if it will help, but easy enough to check.

Good luck!

EDIT
If you want the alert to span the full width, perhaps something like:

```
.alert{
position:absolute;
width:90%;
right:20px;
top:45px;
]
```

Comment: ok, that removes the space but now instead of spanning the whole page, it's just a small alert at the right side. I removed 20px and replaced it with width: 100% which makes it span the whole page, but now the `x` to remove the alert isn't displayed. Why did you do right: 20px?

Comment: 20px sets the right edge of the alert div. Please see my edit to see if that helps @Leahcim

Comment: Thanks for trying. It doesn't look the same as the original. It's sort not reaching to the edge of the screen on either side (due to 90%) but not really centered either due to the 20px on the one end. .

Comment: It's on local host right now. I might have it online in a few days in which case I'll post a link if I can't figure it out before then.